# Как сохранять полученные данные в формате JSON? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post, firebase-database

**Условие**:

- я получаю данные с сервера (через API key) через `fetch().then(response => response.json()).then(data => data)`

**Задача**:

- сохранять результат каждого запроса в свой, локальный json файл.

**Вопрос**:

- это возможно? Какие инструменты для этого нужны? (намекаю на node.js)
- или достаточно использовать какой-то метод? (мб метод POST)
- если для такой задачи необходим сервер, подойдет ли FireBase?

---

Спасибо Вам!

Comment: А что собственно мешает после fetch с помощью Nodejs модуля fs сохранить в файл response.json()?

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет! Я попробую в этом разобраться и отпишусь

Answer (score 3):

Да, это возможно. Обычно это делается через создание временного элемента `a`, который не добавляют на станицу

> Перед запуском убедитесь, что Роскомнадзор не сломал сайт https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ у вашего интернет провайдера!

```
(async function() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    const json = await response.text();
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([json], {type: "application/json;charset=utf-8;"}));
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download='sample.json';
    a.href=url;
    a.click();
})();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я попробую так сделать и напишу о результате!